# Efficiency of iOS and Android in testing a word if it's correct

Tags: android, ios, iphone, performance, search

I have an app idea that relies on words... I'm still in the game design phase, and am concerned about the testing of the word for correctness. Given my research a database of English words is about 50K+.

Given the power of an iPhone, iPad or Android, will I need to create a tree hash of some kind for this data, or will an array suffice? I've never really worked with anything that big before...

I know there is a method for ios for searching an array...

```
BOOL isTheObjectThere = [myArray containsObject: @"my string"];
```

Which would make my life easy, but I'm unsure if this would be efficient in the real world.

I don't have a development environment for either android or iOS for another couple of months, my primary platform will be iOS, then Android, hence the objective-C code references.

*Edit after first answer:*

I found a binary search method for objective C, will definitely give this a whirl once I get my development environment sorted.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = ... // must be sorted
id searchObject = ...
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [sortedArray count]);
NSUInteger findIndex = [sortedArray indexOfObject:searchObject 
                                    inSortedRange:searchRange
                                    options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual
                                        usingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                                        {
                                            return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                                        }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform doesn't really matter for your problem.

If you store the dictionary in an alphabetically sorted array then you can test for a word in O(log n), that's about 15 steps for n=50k.

Comment: Hmmm, seems I should have revised some of my C notes... Seems sometimes I get stuck thinking in Arrays and Hashtables and nothing else. This Answer seems most straight forward and logical, and shouldn't provide me with any headaches during implementation because I can easily provide a sorted array of dictionary words, that isn't a hassle, and implementing a binary search as edited in my question seems like is a cake walk in objective-c.